# Creating a Parse service with async calls to return a response

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, uiviewcontroller

Building my first Swift app and using Parse for the Baas. 
I'm wrapping it in a service, so that I can check the data inputs and prepare the results...to make my life easier. But I'm not sure how I can use async calls with it.

I typically have my services return a response with `success: Bool`, `message: String` (reasons for the error) and `data: [AnyObject]` for results.  I come from a JS world and I'm used to callbacks, but not sure how this works here, since blocks don't return data...

```
class UserService {                    
    class func register(email: String, password: String) -> Response {    
        if email == "" || password == "" {
            return Response(success: false, message: "Please enter an email and password")
        }

        var user = PFUser()
        user.username = email
        user.email = email        

        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
             if let error = error {
                 let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
                 // here I would like to return my response success: false, message: errorString
             } else {
                 // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                 // Here I would like to return response success: true
             }
        }
        return Response(success: true, message: "")
    }
```

For info, here is how I call the service in my ViewController

```
@IBAction func registerBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
        registerBtnBtn.enabled = false
        let response: Response = UserService.register(emailInput.text, password: passwordInput.text)
        if !response.success {
            registerBtnBtn.enabled = true
            registerBtnBtn.setTitle("Registering", forState: .Normal)

            AlertTools.okAlert(self, title: "Something went wrong...", message: response.message)
        } else {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("registerToBabySegue", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

Am I going at this completely wrong? 
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use completion handlers (blocks) as Apple uses in their frameworks:

```
typealias Response = (success: Bool, message: String?)

class UserService {
    class func register(email: String, password: String, completionHandler: ((Response)->())?) {
        if email == "" || password == "" {
            completionHandler?(Response(success: false, message: "Please enter an email and password"))
            return
        }

        let user = PFUser()
        user.username = email
        user.email = email

        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
                completionHandler?(Response(success: false, message: errorString))
                // here I would like to return my response success: false, message: errorString
            } else {
                completionHandler?(Response(success: true, message: nil))
                // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                // Here I would like to return response success: true
            }
        }
        completionHandler?(Response(success: true, message: nil))
    }

}

UserService.register("some@email.com", password: "12345") { (response: Response) -> () in
    // process response
}
```